# Conditional @PostConstruct annotation

Tags: spring, conditional-statements, javabeans, postconstruct

I sometimes may not need to post-construct of a bean at startup according to values passed via JVM argument.

I tried `@Conditional` annotation but it only works on `@Bean` annotations.

Have you tried/needed such a thing before?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Conditional can not be mix with postconstruct. So my suggetions

1. Add two diferent beans one with postconstruct and one without as use `@Conditional` in beans declaration
2. Add programatic code validatiing your application args like:

   ```
   import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

   private final Environment env;

   public void execute() {
       if (env.getProperty("condition") == "condition") {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use aproximation in 1 but  `@Profile` and pass active profile as parameter `-Dspring.profiles.active=my_profile`